# Batch Normalization in TensorFlow during validation and training

Tags: tensorflow

I think I am making some mistake in using Batch Normalization during training vis-a-vis validation. This is because the validation loss does not decrease and validation error is always 1.0

I would really appreciate some help on getting it right.

My TensorFlow model is declared as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf


class OverFeatAccurateBase(object):
    def __init__(self, minibatch, numclasses):
        self._numclasses = numclasses
        self._trainmode = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
        self._logits = self._buildmodel(minibatch)

    @property
    def numclasses(self):
        return self._numclasses

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._trainmode

    @property
    def logits(self):
        return self._logits

    def _bn(self, input, is_training, name):
        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(input, fused=True, renorm=True, training=is_training,
                                      reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                                      name=name)
        return out


    def _buildmodel(self, minibatch):
        out = tf.layers.conv2d(minibatch, filters=96,
                               kernel_size=[7, 7],
                               strides=[2, 2],
                               padding='valid',
                               data_format='channels_first',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=0.00001),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv1')

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm1', training=self.mode)

        out = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(out, pool_size=[3, 3],
                                      strides=[3, 3],
                                      padding='valid',
                                      data_format='channels_first',
                                      name='pool1')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=256,
                               kernel_size=[7, 7],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='valid',
                               data_format='channels_first',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=0.00001),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv2')

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm2', training=self.mode)



        out = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(out, pool_size=[2, 2],
                                      strides=[2, 2],
                                      padding='valid',
                                      data_format='channels_first',
                                      name='pool2')

        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=512,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_first',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=0.00001),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv3')

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm3', training=self.mode)


        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=512,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_first',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=0.00001),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv4')

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm4', training=self.mode)



        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=1024,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_first',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=0.00001),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv5')

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm5', training=self.mode)



        out = tf.layers.conv2d(out, filters=1024,
                               kernel_size=[3, 3],
                               strides=[1, 1],
                               padding='same',
                               data_format='channels_first',
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                   stddev=0.01,
                                   seed=0),
                               bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                               kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                   scale=0.00001),
                               reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                               name='conv6')

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm6', training=self.mode)



        out = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(out, pool_size=[3, 3],
                                      strides=[3, 3],
                                      padding='valid',
                                      data_format='channels_first',
                                      name='pool3')

        out = tf.layers.flatten(out, name='flatten')

        out = tf.layers.dense(out, units=4096, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                  stddev=0.01,
                                  seed=0),
                              bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                  scale=0.00001),
                              reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                              name='full1'
                              )

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=-1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm7', training=self.mode)



        out = tf.layers.dense(out, units=4096, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                              kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                  stddev=0.01,
                                  seed=0),
                              bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                              kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(
                                  scale=0.00001),
                              reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                              name='full2'
                              )

        out = tf.layers.batch_normalization(out, axis=-1, renorm=True, fused=True, name='batchnorm8', training=self.mode)



        logits = tf.layers.dense(out, units=self.numclasses,
                                 kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal(
                                     stddev=0.01,
                                     seed=0),
                                 bias_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0),
                                 reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE,
                                 name='output'
                                 )

        return logits
```

For executing the graph, I do as follows (to see full code you can [go here](https://github.com/calledbymountains/OverFeat/blob/master/trainbasenet.py) )

**VALIDATION**

```
  [loss, top1, top5, epoch, summaries_val,
                                         top1_update, top5_update], feed_dict={net.mode: False, netmode: False})
```

**TRAINING**

```
 _, loss_value, top1_err, top5_err, eph, summaries, _, _, _ = sess.run(
                            [update_ops, loss, top1, top5, epoch, summaries_train, train_op,
                             top1_update,
                             top5_update], feed_dict={net.mode: True, netmode: True})
```

In the above lines, `net` is the object of class `OverFeatAccurateBase`
`netmode` is a placeholder whose value determines if the data is read from training set or validation set.

Comment: Can you post the data you use, or at least some of it? I'm willing to give this one a try but can't run without the data.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan
You can find a subset of the data at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QIPsJDjKlNz0wGUUd9OGFTFkR3G1pXi-

Comment: Managed to download and run it. After 123 epochs, training loss is 2.83, validation loss is 8.214, error is 1.0 for both: `INFO:tensorflow:TRAIN : Epoch[123], Iter[6027] Time for 100 iterations[9.120sec]- Loss=2.830, Top1 error=1.00, Top5 error=1.00
INFO:tensorflow:VALIDATION : Epoch[123], Iter[6076] Time for 100 iterations[0.976sec] - Loss=8.214, Top1 error=1.00, Top5 error=1.00` Is that similar to what you have? At what epoch does training loss starts to decrease?

Comment: It is very similar to what I observe. The training loss starts decreasing in about 1 epoch from 7.3 to 5.9  in 1 epoch (1.2 million images), but validation loss only increases from about 9 to 10.

Comment: What about the Top1 and Top5 errors? Those stay 1.0 for me for both.

Comment: Maybe because the subset u have is very small and incomplete.
for me top1 and top5 decreases for training but stay at 1.0 for validation

Comment: If the subset is small, it should overfit like crazy and training Top1 Top5 should decrease a lot, but validation stay up. I'm worried something is not right with the way I'm running this.

Comment: Well, I just took a random subset of data. I hv not checked it but maybe the subset does not contain all 1000 classes and the validation does not contain all 1000 classes as well. So, in such a case it may happen. But i am perplexed that after 123 epochs u dont see any improvement. i dont find anything in the code to suggest otherwise. But i'm willing to take a look now.

Comment: It's up to epoch 150 now and training loss is down to about 2.8, validation loss 8.3. Those are radically different, so I can take a look at that. Not sure what's going on with Top1/Top5. If it's only a subset of classes, then it should be even better.

Comment: https://github.com/calledbymountains/OverFeat/blob/master/trainbasenet.py#L72-L94 shows the metrics calculation. I do not see anything wrong here.

Comment: But anyways there is a problem, because validation loss does not decrease at all.

Comment: Yes, the main issue is reproduced. Let me take a look.

Comment: You can see a run sample screenshot at https://imgur.com/a/YWfcPyW
The above is for vgg16 training but the point remains

Comment: `numtrain = 1281167` and `numval = 50000` shouldn't those be changed for a subset?

Comment: numtrain and numval dont affect metric calculation

Comment: TensorFlow people should provide a complete end-to-end example of training a large network from scratch.

Comment: It doesn't look to be batch normalization-related. When I force BN to be in training mode all the time, the discrepancy still remains. I'm trying some other stuff now.

Comment: I can fairly confidently rule out BN as a source of the problem. When I use the training data to do validation, but the network is the same as it would be otherwise, it does give normal values (the exact same as for training.) So the network seems to operate correctly. But I can confirm that with the validation set the loss actually increases. I've printed the images supplied to the network and they also look okay. Labels too. I don't have any good ideas how to proceed right now. I'll come back if anything comes to my mind.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this is the problem, but I'm not just able to comprehend that you're applying batchnorm after passing through the activation layer (RELU). 
According to the literature I've seen so far, BN is generally included right after the Conv layer and then an activation after normalization. Normalization on already modified values (-ve values changed to 0) doesn't seem to be right.
I don't know if this solves your problem, but can you try having activation=None in Conv layer and having activation after the BN layer.

Comment: @End-2-End Please see https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/67gonq/d_batch_normalization_before_or_after_relu/

Comment: What are the labels?. Thought it was a regression problem(bounding box), but your code seems to reflect classification (softmax)?. Can you add details ?

Comment: No it was always about classification. This code is an attempt to replicate the first stage of OverFeat which involves training the overfeat network for classification.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded the data sets you gave and checked the images. I found that in the validation set, the labels are disordered. So check the data.

---

### In the training set with label index = 1, three examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

### In the validation set with label index = 1, three examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]